# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. POO C#

Tags: c#, poo

Gente, buena noche, tengo este fragmento de código que en resumen con un arreglo de tamaño 2 funciona piola esa condición pero si doy más de 3 en tamaño al arreglo "inmobiliaria" pues me salta el error-
lo que quiero hacer es que verifique que una nueva clave no sea igual a una ingresada anteriormente
de eso se encarga "Check()" como dato adicional, el error salta (por ej con 4 espacios) cuando agrego una clave nueva en el indice 1. no estoy usando get,set,this ¿será por eso?. soy nuevo en POO a lo mucho llevo invertidas 48hrs. Rotulos(); no es mas que WritLine's diciendo que la clave ya existe, 1 ReadKey() y 1 Clear();

```
     Class CApartamento
     {
        public string Clave;
        ...;
        public CApartamento[] inmobiliaria;

        Console.Write("Cuantos Registros?: ")
        tam = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        inmobiliaria = new CApartamento[tam];

        for(int i=0, j=1; inmobiliaria.Length; i++)
        {
            inmobiliaria[i] = new CAparamento();                

            Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
            //inmobiliaria[i].clave = Console.ReadLine();
            temporary_key = Console.ReadLine();

            if (j == i)
            {
                do
                 {
                    if(Check(inmobiliaria, temporary_key)) 
                    {
                       ///me lo recalca aca arriba tambien(leer 
                       ///mas abajo xD)

                       Rotulos();
                       existe = true;
                       Console.WriteLine("    .------------------.");
                       Console.WriteLine("    + INGRESANDO DATOS +");
                       Console.WriteLine("    .------------------.");
                       Console.WriteLine("\n");

                       Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
                       temporary_key = Console.ReadLine();
                       
                    }
                    else
                        {
                           j++;
                           existe = false;
                        }
                        
                } while (existe != false);

              inmobiliaria[i] = temporary_key;
         }
          else
              {
                 inmobiliaria[i] = temporary_key;
              }
         }
    }

           private bool Check(CApartamento[] inmobiliaria, string temporary_key)
           {
              bool existe = true;

              for(int i=0; i<inmobiliaria.Length;)
              {
                  if(inmobiliaria[i].clave != null && inmobiliaria[i].clave.CompareTo(temporary_key) == 0) 
                  {
                       ///aca se genera un error
                       ///cuando quiere buscar en más de 2 posiciones, y me 
                        ///lo recalca arriba el error
                     existe = true;
                     break;
                  }
                  else
                     {
                         existe = false;
                     }
              }

             return existe;
           }
```

Comment: en que parte te salta la excepción?

Comment: en el if del metodo Check.

Comment: Tu código es funcional ? Ya que ademas de los errores que han dado en las respuestas, hay otros como que por ejemplo asignas al objeto inmobiliaria[i] que es del tipo CApartamento un valor de tipo String, tu codigo deberia darte error incluso antes de llegara entrar en if(j == i)

Comment: si funciona dude, la primera parte de ese code está dentro de un método llamado IngresarDatos(); y arriba de él están definidas las variables que pido, clave(string) extension(string), precio(float) etc. públicas porque las ocupo en el main.

Comment: si te es posible, agrega el codigo de manera que sea reproducible y asi ver donde está el problema, ya que no se como es tu clase CApartamento, ni como inicias el array inmobiliaria

Comment: lo intentaré, creo que existía una norma en este sitio que dictaba que no está permitido colocar todo el código porque la idea es pedir ayuda, no que hagan la tarea los demás.

Comment: No el codigo completo, solamente minimo y verificable: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrego un codigo funcional; Lo he editado en un proyecto cambiando ciertas cosas de tu codigo.
He agregado como clase `CApartamento`, la cual servirá de modelo para organizar los datos.
Tu ejemplo tiene varios fallos que ya te han mencionado en otras respuestas, asi como en mi comentario en tu pregunta.
Uno de los principales, del cual creo que estás formulando tu pregunta, es que cuando inicias el array `inmobiliaria`  y se lo envias a tu funcion `Check`, no copruebas si la posicion ya ha sido inicializada: Si tu array contiene 5 valores, pero estás en la posicion 0, los siguientes 1, 2, 3 y 4 aun no han sido inicializados por lo tanto te dará error.
No obstante y como mencionas que estás aprendiendo, podrias echar un vistazo al uso de  [listas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1), que en tu caso, seria la opción que yo elegiria.

```
namespace CApartamento
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.Write("Cuantos Registros?: ");

        CApartamento[] inmobiliaria = new CApartamento[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];


        for (int i = 0; i < inmobiliaria.Length; i++)
        {
            inmobiliaria[i] = new CApartamento();
            Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
            String temporary_key = Console.ReadLine();

            while (Check(inmobiliaria, temporary_key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    .------------------.");
                Console.WriteLine("    + INGRESANDO DATOS +");
                Console.WriteLine("    .------------------.");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");

                Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
                temporary_key = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            inmobiliaria[i].clave = temporary_key;
        }
    }


    private static bool Check(CApartamento[] inmobiliaria, string temporary_key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inmobiliaria.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inmobiliaria[i] != null && inmobiliaria[i].clave != null && inmobiliaria[i].clave.CompareTo(temporary_key) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}


public class CApartamento
{
    public String clave;
    /* otros objetos*/



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código puede estar generando el error, debido a que has instanciado la variable `inmobiliaria` con una capacidad, y no has asignado valores para cada uno de sus componentes, cuando haces referencia a uno de sus componentes y este es nulo, lanza el error, pero además tu método  `Check` contiene otro error evidente y es que declaras y asignas valor `true` a la variable `existe` y luego dentro del bloque `if`le asignas de nuevo valor `true`como resultado tu método  `Check` devolverá siempre `true` sea cual sea el resultado de la condicional `if`. Con el siguiente código, ninguno de esos errores ocurrirá.

```
   private bool Check(CApartamento[] inmobiliaria, string temporary_key)
           {
              //Se declara y se asigna valor false a la variable existe 
              bool existe = false;

              for(int i=0; i<inmobiliaria.Length;)
              {
                  if(inmobiliaria[i] != null && inmobiliaria[i].clave.CompareTo(temporary_key) == 0) 
///aca se verifica que el valor inmobiliaria[i].clave sea diferente de nulo, evitando el error
                  {
                    //Se asigna valor true a la variable existe.
                     existe = true;
                  }
              }

             return existe;
           }
```

Comment: aún no resolvió el problema :/ verificar si el arreglo no es null, sobre la variable existe, le asigné true en la definición porque el return me exigía asignar un valor pero si agregué el respectivo else con existe = false. solo que no lo agregué en la descripción del problema aquí.

Comment: piola dude, lo solucionaste nada más que la condición del arreglo distinto de null, era sin la variable clave. inmobiliaria[i] != null.

Comment: @Host_Mung Calro amigo, si te explico en la respuesta que hay que verificar precisamente que ninguno de los elementos del arreglo`inmobiliaria` sea nulo y el código de mi respuesta vuelvo a hacer referencia a sus valores. Edito la respuesta para quien la vea pueda entender la solución, eso puede ayudar a otros, si lo crees justo, marca y puntea mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El fallo pueda estar en las tres primeras líneas de código:

```
Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
inmobiliaria[i].clave = Console.ReadLine();
temporary_key = inmobiliaria[i].clave;
```

Lo que lees de consola ya lo tratas de guardar en inmobiliaria[i].clave y creo que debería ser así:

```
Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
temporary_key = = Console.ReadLine();
```

Después de tener el dato introducido en temporary_key es cuando compruebas si ya existe dicho elemento en tu array inmobiliaria[]. Ten en cuenta las correcciones de Eduardo Reyes en la función Check.

Espero haber sido de ayuda aunque sólo has mostrado parte del código, no sabemos de dónde viene esa i, ni su valor ni tampoco qué función tiene la condicional j==i.

Bueno; entendiendo un poco más lo que pretendes creo que es cuestión de organización. Yo lo haría con List< T > y lo plantearía así:

```
class CApartamento : IEquatable<CApartamento>
{
    public string Clave;
    public string Descripcion;
    public ...

    // Constructor
    public CApartamento(string str_Key)
    {
         Clave = str_Key;
    }

    // Permite la comparación de dos objetos CApartamento
    public bool Equals(CApartamento other)
    {
       return (this.Clave == other.Clave);
    }
}

// Esta quedaría obsoleta si usamos List<T>.Contains()
private bool ExistKey(List<CApartamento> inmobiliaria, string temporary_key)
{
    foreach(CApartamento CA in inmobiliaria)
    {
        if (CA.Clave == temporary_key) return true;      
    }
    return false;
}
```

Luego en tu cuerpo de programa o método encargado ponemos:

```
List<CApartamento> inmobiliaria = new List<CApartamento>();

bool SeguirMetiendoDatos = true;

while( SeguirMetiendoDatos == true )
{
    // Introducimos una clave
    Console.Write("CLAVE [A-###]: ");
    temporary_key = Console.ReadLine();
    // Creamos nuestro objeto provisional con la clave introducida
    CApartamento CA = new CApartamento(temporary_key);

    // *** if (ExistKey(inmobiliaria, temporary_key)  **
    // Este IF es innecesario ya que dotamos a nuestra clase
    // con la capacidad de compararse y por lo tanto podemos usar
    // el método Contains de la lista inmobiliaria

    if (inmobiliaria.Contains(CA))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("El elemento ya existe, introduzca otra clave.");
    }
    else // Si no existe lo añadimos a la lista
    {
         // Rellenamos nuesto objeto CApartamento con
         // el resto de datos antes de añadirlo a la lista.
         CA.Descripcion = ...;

         // Lo incluimos en la lista  
         inmobiliaria.Add(CA);

         Console.Write("Introducir otra clave (S/N): ");
         string respuesta = Console.ReadLine();

         SeguirMetiendoDatos = (respuesta.ToUpper() == "S");
    }
}
```

El hecho de usar List nos permite operaciones como Añadir o Borrar dinámicamente elementos de la lista, ordenarlos... a la vez que nos permite simplificar el código y añadirle legibilidad.

Comment: lo intenté pero sigue sin solucionarse :[ adicional al msj "referencia de obj no establecida...", abajo me dice que "inmobiliaria[] fue null", en la pantalla de mensajes de visual studio.

Comment: En qué parte del código declaras inmobiliaria y donde se inicializa. Si te da el error de que es null es que no has asignado nada. Tendrías que hacer algo así CApartamento[] inmobiliaria = new CApartamento[0]. Podrías mostrar más código. Y qué misión tiene el bucle no logro alcanzar lo que pretendes.

Comment: ya agregué en donde le asigno espacio a inmobiliaria, el bucle for es para ir agregando los valores para la inmobiliaria, precio, extension, clave etc. la "i" es el indice del arreglo, y la "j=1" es para que comience a verificar si la clave nueva es igual a la ingresada anteriormente, en el indice i=0. el ciclo do while se encarga de que el usuario ingrese una clave diferente.

Comment: Creo que en el bulce for te falta la condicional i < inmobiliaria.Length; con lo que si i llega a valer length daría error. Además cada elemento del array lo inicializas previo a comprobar, además asignas a un objeto CApartamento un string cuando has visto que no existe.

Comment: He extendido la respuesta plantándolo de otra forma. Espero que sirva.

Comment: en el visual studio si tenía esa i < inmobiliaria.Length pero aca se me pasó jeje.

Comment: el error estaba en el if del método Check, era inmobiliaria[i] != null jeje y lo estaba haciendo con los arreglos clásicos porque en el 2do ejercicio propuesto me toca hacer el mismo código pero con Listas, me diste un empujón para ello dude muchas gracias.